# Getting rid of space between progress bar and entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

A template I borrowed and edited for a boiler plate for my code using tkinter and customtkinter
i wanted to add a table but firstly adjust the spacing between the progress bars and entry widget

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter
import CTkTable

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.title("GameBenchMark")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # create sidebar frame with widgets
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="GameBenchMark", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        self.appearance_mode_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Appearance Mode:", anchor="w")
        self.appearance_mode_label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.sidebar_frame, values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                                                       command=self.change_appearance_mode_event)
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # create main entry and button
        self.entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=1, padx=(20, 0), pady=(20, 20), sticky="new")

        self.main_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, text='Search', fg_color="transparent", border_width=2, text_color=("gray10", "#DCE4EE"))
        self.main_button_1.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=(20, 20), pady=(20, 20), sticky="nw")

        # create slider and progressbar frame
        self.slider_progressbar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, fg_color="transparent")
        self.slider_progressbar_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0), sticky="new")
        self.slider_progressbar_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.slider_progressbar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.progressbar_1 = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(self.slider_progressbar_frame)
        self.progressbar_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(10, 0), pady=(10, 0), sticky="new")
        self.progressbar_2 = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(self.slider_progressbar_frame)
        self.progressbar_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(10,0), pady=(10, 0), sticky="new")


        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.set("Dark")
        self.progressbar_1.configure(mode="indeterminnate")
        self.progressbar_1.start()



    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, new_appearance_mode: str):
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I want to remove the space between them completely.

[image]

I have tried adjusting sticky as well as pad and row column values

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question previously. I have updated the answer. Please take a look and let me know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `row=0` and `pady=(50,0)` in `self.slider_progressbar_frame` as follows:

```py
self.slider_progressbar_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(10,0), pady=(50, 0), sticky="new")
```

The output with the above code change is:

[image]